# Bootstrap: Make columns stack horizontally in row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation where I want to make the columns stack horizontally in the row.

The row should stretch horizontally to accommodate these columns. I've tried using `white-space: nowrap` on the row, cleared floats on columns and made them display as inline blocks. This works, but the row doesn't stretch horizontally to cover the columns

The row and column belong to a parent container that should scroll horizontally as the row stretches.

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/afhq9pyr/

Comment: Have you tried to polyfill for IE11? https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility

Comment: **Flexbox** is supported by **IE11** and **IE10** http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Yeah I have updated the question. using the polyfill might help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Flex](http://bennettfeely.com/flexplorer/) CSS Method. Is currently [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) by all the browsers

```
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
    -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
    flex: 1 auto;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afhq9pyr/1/) updated with the Flex method.

Comment: Flexbox is the best solution for what you want to achieve @Ladmerc, by default bootstrap is built as a 12 column grid and when your columns equal to 12 they default and begin in a new "row". Using flexbox achieves the result you are after.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it scrollable as in the original fiddle